rename files from 1 digit increment to 3 digit one
I have many files such as:
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-1.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-2.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-3.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-4.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-5.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-6.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-7.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-9.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-10.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-11.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-12.pdf
[...]
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-1.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-2.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-3.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-4.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-5.pdf
[...]
darin_lab_dar04-15-54.pdf

Note: Original question was using a generic filenames ("file1" "file2".
Files are named with a filename (different for each) and an increment. There is no recurrent pattern for the filename and it could contain several -, _.
I would like to rename these files (in bash) by transforming the increment to obtain 3 digit one. Expected result is:
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-001.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-002.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-003.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-004.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-005.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-006.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-007.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-011.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-012.pdf
[...]
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-002.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-003.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-004.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-005.pdf
[...]
darin_lab_dar04-15-054.pdf

I see mostly posts using methods based on printf "%03d but this only increment and does not transform the increment already in place (so the file2 will not start at 001).
Does someone has a simple solution to this?

printf "%03d" does not 'increment'; printf "%03d" will print a number and left pad with 0's for numbers that are <= 3 digits in length

Usually questions that show no effort from the OP to solve their own problem get downvoted and closed, like the OPs other similar question apparently did. I can't imagine how this one got multiple answers and multiple upvotes.

Use rename for this: rename 's/(\d+).pdf/sprintf("%03d.pdf",$1)/e' kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-*

@EdMorton other similar question: Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix

Assumptions:

all filenames are of the format some_base_string + some number of -number pairs + .pdf
we do not know beforehand any details on the characters that make up some_base_string
we do not know beforehand how many sets of -number strings appear before the .pdf
we want to (left) 0-pad to 3 digits the number in the last -number string (before the .pdf)

Setup:
$ touch kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-7.pdf kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-9.pdf kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-10.pdf kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf darin_lab_dar04-15-1.pdf darin_lab_dar04-15-54.pdf darin_lab_dar04-15-6.pdf some_long_file_name-1-2-3-4-5.pdf yet_another_file-1-2-5678

$ ls -1
darin_lab_dar04-15-1.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-54.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-6.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-10.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf              # filename should not change
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-7.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-9.pdf
some_long_file_name-1-2-3-4-5.pdf
yet_another_file-1-2-5678                 # filename should not change

One idea using a regex to parse filenames into usable components
regex='^(.*-)([^-]+).pdf'
#       ^^^^^-------------------- everything up to and including the last '-'; will be stored in BASH_REMATCH[1]
#            ^^^^^^^------------- the last number (ie, last string containing no hyphens) before the '.pdf'; will be stored in BASH_REMATCH[2]

for fname in *.pdf
do
    [[ "${fname}" =~ ${regex} ]]
    # typeset -p BASH_REMATCH                                # uncomment to see contents of BASH_REMATCH[]

    last="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"                                # grab last number
    printf -v last03 "%03d" "${last}"                        # left pad with 0's

    [[ "${last}" != "${last03}" ]] &&                        # if different then ...
    echo mv "${fname}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${last03}.pdf"     # remove the 'echo' to perform the actual rename/mv operation
done

This generates:
mv darin_lab_dar04-15-1.pdf darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
mv darin_lab_dar04-15-54.pdf darin_lab_dar04-15-054.pdf
mv darin_lab_dar04-15-6.pdf darin_lab_dar04-15-006.pdf
mv kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-10.pdf kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
mv kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-7.pdf kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-007.pdf
mv kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-9.pdf kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
mv some_long_file_name-1-2-3-4-5.pdf some_long_file_name-1-2-3-4-005.pdf

NOTES:

this only prints the mv commands; once satisfied with the new names just remove the echo from the script and run again to execute the mv commands
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf and yet_another_file-1-2-5678 do not show up in the list since their respective last numbers will not be (left) padded with 0's, so the filenames do not change
this should be pretty fast/efficient since we do not spawn any subshells (eg, $(echo ...), ... | bc, $(printf ...))

If we remove the echo and rerun the script:
$ ls -1
darin_lab_dar04-15-001.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-006.pdf
darin_lab_dar04-15-054.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-007.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-009.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-010.pdf
kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-150.pdf              # filename did not change
some_long_file_name-1-2-3-4-005.pdf
yet_another_file-1-2-5678                 # filename did not change


I think this is the most elegant solution but it does not work if file1 or file3 contains number. The actual name of one files is kiril_lab_poi08-4-17.pdf and this script outputs kiril_lab_poi08.004.17.pdf instead of kiril_lab_poi08-4-017.pdf

@ppr well, the answer works for the sample filenames provided in the question; if your real life filenames are different, especially format-wise, from what you've provided in the question then you need to update the question with a more realistic set of sample filenames; you increase the chances of getting a working solution when you provide a more realistic, exhaustive set of sampls to work with

yep, sorry for that. I was trying to post a generic question but it is more useful to use the precise filename. I updated the question with a note.

embedding a note in the question is not sufficient; as currently posted the highlighted filenames (file#-#.pdf) stick out like a sore thumb and that's what people will (initially) focus on; please take a few minutes to update the question to remove the bogus file*-*.pdf files and instead provide a list of 5-10 realistic filenames from your environment, making sure to cover all possible formats

Use rename for this!

for j in 1 2; do 
   for i in $(echo 'for (i=0; i < 100; i++) i' | bc); do  
       mv file$j-$i.pdf file$j-$(printf "%03d" $i).pdf;
   done;
done


What's the purpose of the command substitution? bc does math faster than bash does, yes, but the command substitution and subprocess fork to spin it eats all those savings and then some!

I can never remember the Bourne shell numeric handling.   I am more concerned with my time than the computers.

The Bourne syntax is crufty and hard to remember for sure, but the bash syntax is basically identical to what you're already doing: for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do printf -v i_padded '%03d' "$i" || continue; mv "file$j-$i.pdf" "file$j-$i_padded.pdf"; done -- that's not only faster, it has fewer bugs.

(as a concrete example of a bug, see what happens when you run your original code with IFS=0)

You're looking for something like this:
for src in ./*.pdf; do
  dst=${src%.*}
  inc=${dst##*[!0-9]}
  case ${#inc} in
  1|2) ;;
    *) continue
  esac
  dst=${dst%$inc}$(printf '%03d' $inc).${src##*.}
  echo mv "$src" "$dst"
done

Remove echo if the output looks good.

Use rename for this!

I would create a simplistic script that was more verbose with you on what's going on.
Code Example:
#!/bin/bash

# Loop through each file that matches the pattern
for file in *.pdf; do
    # Extract the number at the end of the filename (after the last dash and before .pdf)
    num=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/.*-\([0-9]\+\)\.pdf/\1/')

    if [[ ${#num} -ge 3 ]]; then
       echo "File '$file' already has a three-digit or larger number. No action needed."
       continue
    fi
    
    # Format the number with leading zeros (e.g., 1 becomes 001)
    new_num=$(printf "%03d" "$num")

    # Construct the new filename with the formatted number
    new_file="${file%-*}-$new_num.pdf"

    if [[ "$file" == "$new_file" ]]; then
       echo "File '$file' already has the correct name. No action needed."
       continue
    fi
    
    # Check if the file already exists
    suffix=1
    while [[ -e "$new_file" ]]; do
       # If it exists, add a suffix before .pdf
        new_file="${file%-*}-$new_num-$suffix.pdf"
       ((suffix++))
    done
    
    # Rename the file (using rename opposed to mv)
    rename "$file" "$new_file"
done

Summary:
Use sed to get the last number of the file name, check if it's less than 3 digits long and if so act on changing it. If the file already exists add a suffix. file...100-1.pdf etc.

Use rename for this!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub opposed to mv ?

alternatively, yes. rename 's/(\d+).pdf/sprintf("%03d.pdf",$1)/e' kiril_lab_poi08-4-17-*

With a recent enough bash (for =~) and without any command substitution:
for f in *.pdf; do
  if [[ $f =~ ^(.*[^0-9])([0-9]{1,2})\.pdf$ ]]; then
    printf -v n '%s%03d.pdf' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    mv "$f" "$n"
  fi
done

This will rename all files like anythingND.pdf to anythingN00D.pdf, and all files like anythingNDD.pdf to anythingN0DD.pdf (where N is a non-digit character and D are digits). It will not rename files with no or more than 2 digits before .pdf.
